# Energy/Efficiency Calculations for Large Multi-stage Package HVAC

Tags: hvac, cooling, energy-efficiency

I frequently use the Equivalent Full Load Hour (EFLH) estimation method to calculate the expected energy usage for commercial HVAC equipment.  While not ideal, it works well enough to given an order of magnitude for the energy savings that we can expect if and when equipment is replaced.  The EFLH can usually be approximated well enough form available tables for different building types in various locations, and the efficiency, usually in the form of SEER or EER, is typically right in the product data.

While working on a large manufacturing plant, I came across a slew of 50-ton Trane Voyager rooftop package units. The high efficiency versions of these units have 5 stages, but do not provide any indication of traditional efficiencies that I am used to seeing throughout their literature.
https://www.trane.com/content/dam/Trane/Commercial/global/products-systems/equipment/unitary/rooftop-systems/voyager-commercial-27-1-2-to-50-tons/RT-PRC033L-EN_05112019.pdf

Is there a straightforward way to go about calculating energy usage for equipment like this?

Comment: Why not data log the power input - voltage, current and power factor...

Comment: @SolarMike, that would be ideal, but these calculations are at the front end of the sales cycle and are largely used to provide an order of magnitude for the savings that might be realized if we helped them replace the equipment - hence the rough estimation method.  On buildings like this one, we don't have any logged historical data and without the customer's decision to move forward, we don't really have any means to acquire the data.  Particularly on a staged system, we would need a fair amount of data to show the trends.

Comment: I see EER and IEER values listed in table 1 on page 29 -- are you looking for something different?

Comment: @LShaver, I'm not sure what to say.  I honestly looked at 3 different years of this document, used the find feature to search on EER, and then manually browsed through the different tables and sections looking for that.  I even looked at that table in particular and was disappointed that it "only" showed heating efficiency (or so I thought).  Thank you for the assist.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a fresh set of eyes :)